# Apply layout files to styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-styles

So in Android's resources, you can apply an item with the type layout to point to a specific layout file. This is great for re-use across different devices. But how can this be applied to specific styles?

```
<attr name="item_name" format="reference" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="item_name">@layout/layout_name</item>
</style>
```

Something like the above will not work. It will produce an inflate error when trying to apply a layout to something like an Activity.

**EDIT:**

Well I figured it out myself. Here is how this is done.

res/values/attr.xml

```
<attr name="item_name" format="reference" />
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="item_name">@layout/layout_name</item>
</style>
```

src/package.name/MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*
         * Get the layout id from the attribute
         */
        TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{R.attr.item_name});
        int layoutId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        a.recycle();

        /*
         * Set the layout
         */
        setContentView(layoutId);
    }
}
```

Now you can switch an entire layout file by switching the style/theme.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have Customize actionbar style.You may use like this

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#de5188</item>
 <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
 <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarSubTitleText</item>
```

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

I hope this one will help you :)

Comment: Yes I know this. But what I want is to base an entire layout file on which style is being used.